# Same key with different flags

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as an input which is the following:

| Key | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Yes |
| 123 | No |
| 567 | No |
| 876 | Yes |

When I have two same keys with different values in the Flag field, I want to keep only the one key with the Flag = Mixed

**Desired Output**

| Key | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Mixed |
| 567 | No |
| 876 | Yes |

Could you please help me to figure it out, by using SQL?

Comment: Brother, I hope you're trying to replace the value if any key is already present, right?  You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to have this output in a query rather than altering the table, You can employ the group_concat() function. This will put your distinct flags into one column with a comma delimiter. You can then put this into a case statement to get your desired output.

```
select `key`,

        group_concat(flag) flag

from temp_db.table

group by `key`
```

| Key | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Yes, No |

```
select `key`

      ,case when flag = 'Yes, No' then 'Mixed'

            else flag end as flag

from (select `key`,

      group_concat(flag) flag

      from temp_db.table

      group by `key`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in two steps:

1. Replace the flag in one of the rows for each key that has both values with `Mixed`.
2. Delete the other row for a key that has a `Mixed` flag.

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.key = t2.key
SET t1.flag = 'Mixed'
WHERE t1.flag = 'Yes' AND t2.flag = 'No';

DELETE t1 
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE t1.flag = 'No' AND t2.flag = 'Mixed';
```

The first query replaces `Yes` with `Mixed` in each pair, the second query deletes the corresponding `No` rows.

Put a transaction around this so that it will be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a new table from this table by using a conditional select query, and rename new table to this current one(namely `t1`) after dropping the table while adding a primary key constraint such as

```
CREATE TABLE t2 AS
SELECT `Key`, CASE WHEN COUNT(`Key`)=2 THEN 'Mixed' ELSE MAX(Flag) END AS Flag
  FROM t1
 GROUP BY `Key`;

DROP TABLE t1;

RENAME TABLE t2 TO t1;

ALTER TABLE t1 ADD PRIMARY KEY(`Key`);
```

where the data throughout the whole table is assumed to have only single or double values for each `Key` column's value

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8eecf9ea281f1237ab1c4ed0651275af)</kbd>